# Ionicons working for Chrome but not for Safari

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari, font-face, ionicons

I can't seem to find out why this is working for Chrome, but not for Safari.

It should look like this:

[image: Should look like this]

But in Safari it looks like the following:

[image]

I can see that the font gets loaded, but the computed font (in console) is Sans-serif.

[image]

In Chrome it does show the correctly used font family

[image]

Comment: Please provide any relevant CSS, different browsers treat default values differently. For instance, are you importing the ionicons with `@font-family`? Also update with the CSS that declares the `font-family` you are mentioning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the font files on the server. I had them pulled by git, but they somehow changed (file size was also different). 
So when I placed them manually on the server, the font was working properly again.